# ASP.NET CORE Roles - Add IdentityRole

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, roles

Im trying to add roles functionality to my app but I'm getting an error message that I don't really understand or know how to fix it.

Im trying to add The IdentityRole to services.AddIdentityCore but getting an error message:

"'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddIdentityCore' and no accessible extension method 'AddIdentityCore' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [API]csharp(CS1061)

[image]

Does anyone know how to implement it right?
What causes this issue ?
Thanks so much for the help

Comment: Use `services.AddIdentity` not `services.AddIdentityCore`

Comment: Okay thank you so much. But if I use AddIdentity. It shows another error regarding the AppUser....

Comment: Sorry for being so ignorant I'm just new to a dotnet

Comment: You're welcome. Comment with the new error. Note: `AppUser.cs` should inherit from `IdentityUser` or use `IdentityUser` directly instead of `AppUser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple. Try this code like below:-

Your `AppUser.cs` model:-

```
  public class AppUser:IdentityUser  
    {
       ... 
    }
```

Your `startup.cs` file:-

```
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(options=> {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                ...
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Try exact same code as above.It will resolve your issue.